# A sci-fi tv BW movie from the 70s with a mini-sub and a kraken

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a BW sci-fi tv movie from the 70s with two marine biologists (man and woman) doing a routine reconnaissance in a mini-sub similar -but smaller- to the Proteus from the 1966 Fantastic Voyage. They were being chased and wrapped up by a kind of Kraken. The scientists used robot arms and small torpedoes to defend themselves from the beast. Finally, the scientists get help from a bigger submarine that blasted with high precision the sea monster who fled back to the black depth of the ocean. Anybody knows what movie is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this may be [It Came from Beneath the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Came_from_Beneath_the_Sea)

> When more people are attacked and killed, the Defense Department
> authorizes Mathews to take out the submarine and fire the torpedo

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot @Dosco Jones. You got it. I just watched and that is the movie. Thumbs up.

Comment: With a six-armed giant octopus!